# Can't show updated image

Tags: jquery, css, url

I have the following code:

**JQuery**

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    var imglink;
    imglink = 'url("http://poweruser.aeiou.pt/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/google.jpg")';
    $('#trick_img').css('content',imglink);

    $(document).on("click","change",function(){
        imglink = 'url("http://poweruser.aeiou.pt/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Google-Gmail.jpg")';
        $('#trick_img').css('content',imglink);
    });

});​
```

**HTML**

```
<image id="trick_img" draggable="false"/><br/>
<button id="change">Change image</button>​
```

**Css**

```
img#trick_img { margin:10px; }
```

**Test Link** 
http://jsfiddle.net/Y5jA9/

**My question is:** How would I do to get the image on the screen changed?

Comment: I want the image to be changed on the screen!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
$(document).on("click","change",function(){
```

Should be changed to:

```
$(document).on("click","#change",function(){
```

To reference the "Change image" button by id

Comment: Thank you! I was missing that detail haha.

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).on("click","#change",function(){
        imglink = 'http://poweruser.aeiou.pt/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Google-Gmail.jpg';
        $('#trick_img').attr('src',imglink);
    });
```

Comment: I liked attr function. i'm using it now! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).on("click","#change",function(){
        var imglink;
        imglink = 'http://poweruser.aeiou.pt/wp-content/uploads/2012/12/Google-Gmail.jpg';
        $('#trick_img').attr('src',imglink);
    });
```

try this

http://jsfiddle.net/Y5jA9/3/

Comment: I liked attr function. i'm using it now! Thank you!